# Displaying limited number of records in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, pagination

Ii have a txt file which contains 2000 rows of data. I want to retrive this data and dispaly in a table form, but i want show some 20-30 records per page and rest numbering the pages like in google.

How do you achieve this in jsp.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [article linked by Jon](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0726-pagination.html), you can use [Displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) which has built-int paging functionality

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into pagination using JSP, there's a tutorial that I found from this great search engine called Google:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0726-pagination.html

It will talk you through the process.

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked <strike>a few</strike> several times before here. Just checkout under each the tags [`pagination` + `jsp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination+jsp). I've answered this topic: [ResultSet to Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination). You may find it useful as well.

DisplayTag is another alternative, but it is not memory efficient as it caches **all** the rows in Java's memory, which might blow if you have thousands of rows and/or thousands of concurrent users. In such case better go ahead with DAO/database-level pagination, as outlined in my answer in the linked topic.

Comment: At least, on the given tags :)