# How to implement pagination in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, pagination

Is there any out-of-the-box, easy to implement, standard pagination component/tag-lib or code-sample available for pagination in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Have a look at [`PagedListHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) and other classes from  [`org.springframework.beans.support`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/support/package-summary.html).

See the JPetstore in the samples for some examples, e.g. in [`SearchProductsController.java`](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/jpetstore/trunk/org.springframework.samples.jpetstore/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/jpetstore/web/spring/SearchProductsController.java):

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
    if (keyword != null) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(keyword)) {
            return new ModelAndView("Error", "message", "Please enter a keyword to search for, then press the search button.");
        }
        PagedListHolder productList = new PagedListHolder(this.petStore.searchProductList(keyword.toLowerCase()));
        productList.setPageSize(4);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("SearchProductsController_productList", productList);
        return new ModelAndView("SearchProducts", "productList", productList);
    }
    else {
        String page = request.getParameter("page");
        PagedListHolder productList = (PagedListHolder) request.getSession().getAttribute("SearchProductsController_productList");
        if (productList == null) {
            return new ModelAndView("Error", "message", "Your session has timed out. Please start over again.");
        }
        if ("next".equals(page)) {
            productList.nextPage();
        }
        else if ("previous".equals(page)) {
            productList.previousPage();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("SearchProducts", "productList", productList);
    }
}
```

Comment: (+1) Hot damn, I had no idea that was there. I must've implemented that functionality at least 3 times, and there it was already...

Comment: cool, By the way, can you please explain, how session is needed in example of SearchProductsController code? I went through the code unable to get use of it.

Comment: @Nachiket Once created, the `PagedListHolder` object is put in the Session, the pagination is actually done on an in memory object. Does this answer your question? If not, can you clarify?

Comment: cool example, was just looking for something like it ;). You can simplify it even more by using RequestParam annotation, thus not needing the Request and Response objects. Thus method signature would look like `public ModelAndView handleRequest(@RequestParam (required = false) String keyword, @RequestParam(required = false) String page, HttpSession session)`. Spring will do then the getParameter part and populate those fields with the corresponding value. As well, it will pass on the HttpSession object directly.

Comment: this means that if the same user opens another search window he won't get other independent set of results, because they're binded to the session?

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a way to do that, too, but didn't find any standard component or taglib. I think mainly because paging can become very specific since you need to retrieve your data with paging from the database already (if you are using Hibernate you can easily do that using the Criteria API). I came up with something like this:

```
public class Pager
{
    private int page;
    private int results;
    private String sortOrder;
    private String sortColumn;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Controller
public class StuffController
{
    @Autowired SomeEntityService someEntityService;

    @RequestMapping("/test.html", method = Method.GET)
    public void getStuffPaged(@RequestParam("id") String id, Pager pager, ModelMap mm)
    {
        mm.addAttribute("entities", someEntityService.get(id, pager));
    }
}
```

If you now perform a request to `http://domain/app/test.html?id=10&page=1&results=30&sortOrder=asc` you will get the pager Object in your request.

Comment: I am not using hibernate, but its cool.. good one.. :)

Comment: Best answer so far! Clean way to bind pagination parameters, works without hibernate too!

Comment: Instead of `Pager` you could use `Pageable` provided by default by Spring

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever heard about the Spring Data JPA project? There is a nice flexible solution using the Pagable interface. I've found it to be the simplest way to achieve clean, boilerplate-free pagination. Check out more at the [Spring Data JPA homepage](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa).

Comment: I looked into it that link and did not find anything jump out at me for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

No one comes to mind and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=spring+pagination) also doesn't reveal any specific components for that (although it gives pretty much concrete examples and hints). But in theory just a bunch of buttons and one (or two) request parameters are more than sufficient. Then let the SQL/DB do its work. I've posted an answer to similar question in JSP/Servlet/DAO context before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination/1987058#1987058).

It basically boils down to pass `firstrow` (index of first row to be displayed in a page) around as request parameter and having two buttons/links in the pagination form which in/decrements the `firstrow` with `rowcount` (amount of rows displayed at once in a page) in combination with a SQL query which returns a subset of the results with help of under each `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` clauses, or subselects, or specific functions, depending on the DB in question. See the aforelinked answer for detailed code examples and SQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a link to the Spring Data JPA reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#web-pagination), where they have a very clean approach to web pagination.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there support for searching on columns?

Comment: Yes. Repos support findByXxx(), findByXxx(Pageable) etc. where xxx is the column.

Answer (score 2):

I published an open source java library focused on pagination with spring framework some time ago.

Although it has not been very successful perhaps someone may be interested in trying it.

There are examples for using it with

- [Swing](http://www.jdal.org/sample/presentation.php)
- [DisplayTag](http://www.jdal.org/doc/displaytag.php)
- [YUI Datatable](http://www.jdal.org/doc/yui-datatable.php)
- [Vaadin](http://www.jdal.org/doc/vaadin.php)

The online examples are somewhat obsolete, better download the jdal-samples file from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdal/files/1.3.1/).