# How to implement pagination using Spring MVC3

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, pagination

I have requirement to implement pagination using Spring MVC 3. I am getting list of 1000 numbers from a Web Service. Now i want to show 5 nos. at a time and when user go to next page then 5 nos and so on. Someone please give me some pointers on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PagedListHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) api.

Similar question is answered check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245035/how-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-mvc-3?lq=1).

This previous link can solve the right away. From GitHub there are new API's that are springing to solve this issue. There is a spring framework tailored pagination, you can take look at some of the links

[spring pagination](http://paginationspring.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Spring MVC, but will work with Spring MVC. [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is a jQuery plugin that nicely formats tabulated data and provides configurable paging out of the box.

Add the following to your JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/resources/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'/>"></script>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

Make sure that your table uses thead and tbody tags on your table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this. I have a list of 1000 + id's and want to show them in 5 at one page and so on. Could you please give me an example.