# Implement pagination in mvc listview with bootstrap table pagination

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have to implement pagination in an ASP.NET MVC list view. I have create view for displaying data in the view. I have used below bootstrap plugin to display data in the table format. The plugin has pagination CSS. I need help to make this pagination working with table data.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/table-panel-with-pagination

Please help me what changes jQuery script I have to write to make this working. I don't want to use any third party plugin like datatable.

I have implemented functionality in above plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Omkar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement pagination in Spring MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245035/how-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-mvc-3)

Comment: I have read that post already this is for java not for .net mvc.