# Large JSF dataTable backed by database that can handle paging/sorting

Tags: java, performance, jsf, datatable, pagination

If have a large amount tabular data that I'm trying to display in a JSF datatable. Are there any any implementations or components out there that can handle database paging and sorting?

I currently have to pull all the rows in the table back and handle paging and sorting client side in JSF. Unfortunately this is not very performant and occasionally causes my app server to run out of memory.

Ideally, this datatable implementation would be able to wrap a JDBC query or a Hibernate query somehow. I'm not stuck on JSF 1.2, I plan on upgrading to 2.0 sometime soon if this matters.

Answer (score 3):

Check out **richfaces** datatable [datatable](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf) with table [filtering](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf) and table [sorting](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/sortingFeature.jsf?)
Or the [extended datatable](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_extendedDataTable.html)

But, yes I forgot one small note :), If you need to go to the database and handle your filtering/sorting on db level you will need to provide your own implementation of DataModel by extending the org.ajax4jsf.model.SerializableDataModel.

There are some blogs going that way, see [this one](http://eclecticprogrammer.com/2008/07/30/a-generic-superclass-for-sorting-and-paginating-in-the-database-with-richfaces/)

Answer (score 2):

You will always have memory problems when the Java code hauls/copies the **entire** dataset of a datastore (e.g. a RDBMS) in Java's memory and then do the sorting and filtering right in Java's memory using Java code. It will get worse when you even store it in the session scope of a webapplication.

The most memory efficient approach is to let the DB do the task where it is invented for. The SQL language offers you under each the `ORDER BY` clause to do the sorting, the `WHERE` clause to do the filtering and the (DB vendor specific) `LIMIT/OFFSET` clauses/subselects/functions to return only a subset of records based on *firstrow* and *rowcount* or *lastrow*. This way you end up with *only* the dataset in Java's memory which is actually to be displayed.

There is no standard JSF component which does exactly that. It will always require the entire dataset being available in the Java memory, because the filtering and sorting needs to happen with pure Java code or Javascripts. JSF knows nothing about SQL, you'll need to provide a custom implementation of [`javax.faces.model.DataModel`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) to the datatable and/or control/manage that in the data access layer yourself. You can get a lot of new insights/ideas and find a kickoff example in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html). You can also find examples of the needed SQL queries in [this JSP-targeted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination) I posted before here.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2007/05/pagination_of_d.html