# Amount of data stored in session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpsession

What technique should we use to make the httpsession object not loaded heavily with data.

Example :

Request 1 ---- >  httpSession loaded with an arraylist of 50,000 different objects. session.setAttribute("data",arraylist);

Request 2 ---- >  httpSession loaded with an arraylist of 40,000 different objects. session.setAttribute("data",arraylist);

Assume the server is loaded heavily with multiple sessions and huge data in them. Let us say from my above example request1..1000 at a time. Which means 1000 session objects with huge data.

What is the alternate way to solve instead storing them in session like this?

Comment: What is the use case that requires storing so much data in the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Be more selective about which data you really need to serve to your client, instead of plonking everything in the Session on the first request you could only load data when the client really needs it (c.q. when a tab is clicked by the user). You can also use specialized lightweight classes instead of your full backend domain classes to pass the data to the frontend.
2. Check your domain model, and see if you can split out any 'static data'. By this I mean data which is commonly shared within your application and does not change a lot, like zipcodes. This type of data is a good candidate for caching and passing by reference, instead of duplicating it.
3. As mentioned, use a caching framework like Ehcache. It reduces the need for plumbing code in your application and allows shared caching across all sessions instead of duplicating the data. Of course if you are only storing user-specific data in your session, then the sharing won't be of big benefit. A framework like that also allows you to configure the caching strategy, for instance so that it will start using the database if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Either put it in the application scope instead (if it is not user-specific), or replace by request-based database-side paging/filtering (if it is user-specific).

I suppose that the data is already stored in a database. Putting it in the application scope does not make much sense then. You will always have memory problems when the Java code hauls/copies the **entire** dataset of a datastore (e.g. a RDBMS) in Java's memory and then do the job right in Java's memory using Java code. It will indeed get worse when you even store/duplicate it in the session scope of a webapplication.

The most memory efficient approach is to let the database do the task where it is invented for. The SQL language offers you under each the `ORDER BY` clause to do the sorting, the `WHERE` clause to do the filtering and the (DB vendor specific) `LIMIT/OFFSET` clauses/subselects/functions to return only a subset of records based on *firstrow* and *rowcount* or *lastrow*. This way you end up with *only* the dataset in Java's memory which is actually to be displayed.

You can find examples of the needed SQL queries in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination) I posted before here. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm talking about eventhough you store the object in 1000's in session(what ever either request,application..) , i want the way not to occupy the memory more. Probably what i'm looking for is some nice design pattern or memory management.

Comment: I think you don't understand me. What do you need those 1000 objects for? To display at once to the enduser? No, that ain't going to work. Only 100 items is already pretty much to be displayed at once. Google also doesn't show zillions of links at once in a single page. They keep the data in a database and use filtering and paging to have only a limited set in memory and display them. You should do the same: keep the data in the database and learn about SQL powers.

Comment: You are talking only about DB retrieval , probabaly i'm looking the answer like what "Boris Pavlović" provided above.

Comment: He's basically suggesting to use a DB to store the data. But if you already use a DB, then you should learn more how to use it to a memory efficient optimum. Just do not unnecessarily duplicate the DB contents into Java's memory. Just program it to return *only* the data of interest **per request** (not per session or application). On the other hand, cloning the entire database in the application scope and only the identifiers in the request or session scope does the same (as boris suggests), but it is not very memory efficient as well.

Comment: Do you ever implemented Lazy fetching? i want some thing like to work on. like "Boris Pavlović" said.. it is a "objects that are staying in a shared pool "

Comment: OK, I give up. Good luck with your application.

Comment: @srinannapa: BTW, if you think Boris'es answer is what you are looking for, it is customary on SO to tell so with an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Store only unique identifiers of objects that are staying in a shared pool (memory, db, flat files)

Comment: Yes i'm looking some thing like this Do you have any example/ scneario of this kind

Answer (score 0):

You could set an attribute on the request, or use forms, if you use the data in the view. If you need to have the data when the session is active, put it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try one of the two alternatives:

- Store the user specific data in your database
- Use a cache system like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) or [memcached](http://memcached.org/)