# display next records by pressing next

Tags: java, servlets, pagination

I have a website in front page. I'm displaying 5 records. I want that when user clicks *Next*, he should be able to view next records. I want to keep track which sublist has already been shown to user. I am using an `ArrayList`. How to get next records each time user clicks on next button, using servlets?

Answer (score 1):

Pass two request parameters on press of the button: `firstrow` and `rowcount`. The `firstrow` represents the index of the first row to be displayed. The `rowcount` represents the amount of rows to be displayed at once.

In the servlet, just do the math. On press of *Next* button do `firstrow += rowcount` and on press of *Prev* button do `firstrow -= rowcount` (simplified example, you of course need to take overflows into account). Then query exactly that subset of data from database using DB-specific SQL, for example `LIMIT firstrow OFFSET rowcount` in MySQL and PostgreSQL. I've posted a more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination) before.