# JDBC ResultSet.absolute() vs. Limit

Tags: java, sql, database, performance, jdbc

What's the preferred method to fetch a subset of records from the database?  Use rs.absolute() or Limit?

Comment: Steven is correct: if you mention which DB server you're using, we would be able to point you the SQL syntax needed for this. In for example MySQL, you could use the `LIMIT` clause. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination) for several DB-specific examples.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly going to be more efficient to craft your SQL to only return the results you want.  It also better expresses your intent.