# How to add pagination in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pagination

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/(
        SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per
        FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW
        WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
        GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE
        ORDER BY TITLE ASC";
        $res = db_query($query) // drupal 7;
```

I am using PHP and SQL (oracle) DB to fetch details. Can any one share the details to add a pager in my page to show only 10 items per page.

```
`function pager_array_splice($res, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {  
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
// Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
$pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);
// We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
$pager_total_items[$element] = count($res);  
$pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);   
$pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));  
return array_slice($res, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}`

`$output = '';
$customArr = pager_array_splice($res, 100);
$output .= theme('views_mini_pager', array('quantity' => 100));
print $output;`

This how i tried for drupal method. But fails.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for pagination in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738181/best-practice-for-pagination-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL**

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/(
SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per
FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW
WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0'
GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
LIMIT $start, 10
";
```

now set $start to `10 * $pageNo`

---

Example:
above sql code.
PHP Code:

```
// show activ page + 5 pages before active page and +5 after that page.
// all in all 11 page numbers:
$maxpagenumber = ...; // thats the tricky part. see below.
$activepage = (int)$_GET['page'];
$startWith = max($activepage-5,1);
$endsWith = min($activepage+5,$maxpagenumber);

// output
echo "first page | prev | ";
for($i=$startswith;$i<=$endsWith;$i++)
  echo $i." | ";
echo "next | last page";
```

you have to add links to the pages above. in each link you append the parameter `page` with the `($i-1)`.

now the part with the $maxpagenumber: you use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your sql statement.

thats all :)

Comment: Thanks Joshua K. Can you share more details or detailed  code.

Comment: added some more code. It should be self-explanatory

Comment: @JoshuaK OP is using **Oracle**, so why did you post **MySQL**? Also, `LIMIT` is not an Oracle syntax.

Comment: Added my code in question. Share some PHP / SQL knowledge to make it as pager. `1 of 20 >>`....`<< 15 of 20 >>`...`<< 20 of 20'

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Pre-12c release**

You could use `ROWNUM` inside **subquery** as **[pagination query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608)**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal
  2  FROM   (SELECT empno, sal, ROWNUM AS rnum
  3          FROM   (SELECT empno, sal
  4                  FROM   emp
  5                  ORDER BY sal)
  6          WHERE ROWNUM <= 8)
  7  WHERE  rnum >= 5;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7654       1250
      7934       1300
      7844       1500
      7499       1600

SQL>
```

**Oracle 12c release**

You could use **Top-n Row limiting** feature.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal
  2  FROM   emp
  3  ORDER BY sal
  4  OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7654       1250
      7934       1300
      7844       1500
      7499       1600

SQL>
```