# Pagination Logic - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pagination

As I'm new to oracle, not sure how to handle the pagination logic.

I need a query that returns the results based on the start vale and the limit value.

See the below resultset

```
id   name
1    abc
2    def
3    ghi
4    jkl
5    qqq
6    www
7    eee
8    ttt
9    yyy
10   uuu
11   iii
12   ppp
13   aaa 
14   sss
15   ddd
16   fff
17   ggg
18   hhh
19   jjj
20   kkk
```

For suppose if I give the values start value = 0 and limit = 5 
then it should return the below records

```
id name
1  abc
2  def
3  ghi
4  jkl
5  qqq
```

if start value = 5 and limit = 15 , then I should return the below result

```
id name
5  qqq
6  www
7  eee
8  rrr
9  ttt
10 yyy
11 uuu
12 iii
13 ooo
14 ppp
15 ddd
16 fff
17 ggg
18 hhh
19 jjj
```

Please help me with the query
Please let me know if anything.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try googling "oracle pagination"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for pagination in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738181/best-practice-for-pagination-in-oracle), or also [Paging with Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle).

Comment: Yeah, I need a query with start value and limit conditions. The links which you provided are with page number and page size/ beginning and end value.

Comment: That's only one of the answers. If you take the time to read the threads, you'll see it has all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use bind variables for this. If you are not familiar with Oracle bind variables, spend 15 minutes reading about them, they are super helpful.

```
select id, name 
from   your_table
where  id between :start_value and :start_value + :limit_value - 1;
```